# JQuery Slideshow error. Pictures list down the page instead of shuffling. Can't find the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so i've been coding a website for my friend and I had everything working and almost ready to publish. But I may have altered something along the way and screwed up the syntax. It could be something as small as a semi-colon (i've searched so it's not that :]). I didnt want to have to ask for your help but I'm stuck. Please assist.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="The Sweetest Sin" />
        <meta name ="keywords" content = "bakery, sweetestsin, sweetest sin" />
        <title>The Sweetest Sin</title>

        <!-- include jQuery library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.slideshow').cycle({
                    fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
                });
            });
        </script>

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Sweetest Sin </a></h1>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li id ="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="flavors.html">Flavors/Fillings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- End Nav -->
            </header>   <!-- End Header -->
            <div id="banner"> </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div id="social-media-icons"> 
                    <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"> <img   src="images/facebook.png" /> </a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/twitter.png" /> </a>
                </div> <!--end social -->

                <div class="left">
                    <div class="canvas">
                        <div class="slideshow">
                            <img src="images/image0.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image2.5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image3.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image3.5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image4.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image4.5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image5.5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />      
                            <img src="images/image6.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image6.5.jpg" width="500" height="350" />
                            <img src="images/image7.jpg" width="500" height="350" /> 
                        </div>  <!-- End Slideshow -->
                    </div> <!-- End Canvas -->
                </div> <!-- End Left -->

                <div class="right">

                    <img src="images/thechef.png"/>
                    <h3>Welcome to the bakery</h3>
                    <p>The Bakery is now open!</p>
                </div> <!-- End Right -->
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy;2012 TheSweetestSin.net</p>
            </footer> <!-- End Footer -->
        </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you set it up on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ben - sorry i have never used this tool but I tried to set it up. As you can see when you run it, instead of the pictures remaining in that div and shuffling, they list one below the other. I cant find this error for my life of me :P. Thanks for taking a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/5egLT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the .slideshow div a fixed height and set the overflow to hidden:

```
.slideshow {
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the slideshow still will not shuffle through the pictures. Now its just a static image.

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console in your browser for errors? Also, are you wrapper the code you posted in $(document).ready()?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked the log and found out that github's cycle plugin ceased to work and I needed to update with the new plugin link.